# Ignoring REST Service Content-Type for JSON with AFJSONRequestOperation?

Tags: ios5, afnetworking

is there a way to ignore the return content type from a Rest Service for a AFJSONRequestOperation ? One of the services i use returns application/text and will not be fixed before the next major release. At the moment i use AFJSONRequestOperation and it fails because of this.

I tried to use:

```
AFHTTPClient *afClient  = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
[afClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
```

But this do not work.

Any other way ?

Thanks, 
Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution for dealing with situations like this is calling `addAcceptableContentTypes:` on the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` subclass that you are using. In your specific situation, add the following snippet to the `initWithBaseURL` method of your `AFHTTPClient` subclass.

```
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/text", nil]];
```

You can read more about `addAcceptableContentTypes:` in [the documentation of AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html#//api/name/addAcceptableContentTypes%3a).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added this some time ago, but needed to change some things because at the end i needed to create the requests manually. Behind this is that i have different servers and the full url needs to be set. AFNetworking uses a base url. But i'm still working with it for the Operation Queue.